# Which combination for uvec2 fragment shader output

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I’ve been trying to output into GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 unsigned values R and G. The texture is set with these *format* / *internal format* / *type* :

```
GL_RG / GL_RG8UI / GL_UNSIGNED_INT
```

I also tried with `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, it results the same issue: incomplete framebuffer.

I output in fragment shader that way:

```
layout (location = 0) vec3 nofrag;
layout (location = 1) uvec2 matfrag;
```

Any idea? I thought `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8` would have been better: well it’s definitely not…

Comment: Can you post the code how you create the FBO, and render onto it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thank you, glYoda! Here’s the solution:

```
GL_RG_INTEGER / GL_RG8UI / GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE
```

I think GL_UNSIGNED_INT is nice too, but since GL**8**UINT, BYTE is far away better.